# Getting the fractional part in math module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've imported the math module
for example, i use

```
math.modf(3.1235324123)
```

it will output

```
(0.1235324123,3.0)
```

how can i get the fractional part?

Comment: Do you mean only the first element? math.modf(3.1235324123)[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tuple expansion](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html):

```
fracpart, realpart = math.modf(3.1235324123)
```

Or, if you only want the fractional part, convention is to use `_` to capture the unwanted argument:

```
fracpart, _ = math.modf(3.1235324123)
```